# Do we need to create process() inside a new annotator?

Tags: opennlp, uima, cleartk

Im creating an annotator called "NewAnnotator" and try to make it works in a pipeline with others annotators in ClearTK like:
SentenceAnnotator, PosTaggerAnnotator, etc. So I want to be able to run pipeline:

```
aggregate.add(SentenceAnnotator.getDescription());
aggregate.add(PosTaggerAnnotator.getDescription());
aggregate.add(NewAnnotator.getDescription());   
// run the classification pipeline on the new texts
SimplePipeline.runPipeline(reader, aggregate.createAggregateDescription());
```

I wrote the code with no error, but when running it returns a lot of errors, which I think from this part in my NewAnnotator code:

```
  public static AnalysisEngineDescription getDescription() throws ResourceInitializationException {
    return AnalysisEngineFactory.createPrimitiveDescription(

          NewAnnotator.class,
          PARAM_POSTAG_MODEL_FILE,
          ParamUtil.getParameterValue(PARAM_POSTAG_MODEL_FILE,  "/somepath")); 
  }
  public static final String PARAM_POSTAG_MODEL_FILE = ConfigurationParameterFactory.createConfigurationParameterName(
      PosTaggerAnnotator.class,
      "postagModelFile");
```

I almost copy this part from PosTaggerAnnotator, but it has no use in my NewAnnotator, I just add in so that I can use:

```
aggregate.add(NewAnnotator.getDescription());
```

because I don't know any other way to add to aggregate without `.getDescription();` and I also don't know how to declare a correct `getDescription()` in my annotator, even it can works fine without it.
So please give me some advise here if you have experienced it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getDescription()` is a convenience method to create a default description for your annotator. It uses [`AnalysisEngineFactory.createPrimitiveDescription()`](http://uimafit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r623/trunk/apidocs/org/uimafit/factory/AnalysisEngineFactory.html#createPrimitiveDescription%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object...%29), to which you need to provide the right arguments, like this:

```
  public static AnalysisEngineDescription getDescription() throws ResourceInitializationException {
    return AnalysisEngineFactory.createPrimitiveDescription(
          NewAnnotator.class,
          first_parameter_name,  first_parameter_value, 
          second_parameter_name, second_parameter_value,
          ... ); 
  }
```

There are more examples in the [uimaFIT codebase](https://code.google.com/p/uimafit/source/browse/trunk/uimaFIT-examples/src/main/java/org/uimafit/examples/tutorial/).

Comment: So is it possible not to declare getDescription() ? but still can add my annotator to the end of the above pipeline (after POSTaggerAnnotator)? I saw your link, most of them don't have getDescription() function. And for mine, no argument to provide. In my process() function, at the end, I will setPos() to get set the process result there, and can get the result of that process by getPos(), similar as POSTaggerAnnotator.

Comment: I tried this: `  public static AnalysisEngineDescription createDescriptor()
      throws ResourceInitializationException {
TypeSystemDescription typeSystemDescription = TypeSystemDescriptionFactory
              .createTypeSystemDescription();
return AnalysisEngineFactory.createPrimitiveDescription(NewAnnotator.class,typeSystemDescription);}
` then in the pipeline I add by : `    aggregate.add(NewAnnotator.createDescriptor());
` but looks like it still the wrong way. Still got lots of errors.

Comment: yes, it is possible not to declare getDescription(), it's just a convenience method to create this annotator's description

Comment: @user1314404 can you paste the errors somewhere (e.g. gist)? Or even better: put the relevant parts of your code on github. Maybe you are missing some required parameters.

Comment: Sure I will do it. I just download github on mac for your request. Im new user of it, not sure how to copy the error/code to that ? Googling..

Comment: Sorry, I still finding way to use it. To save time, I also upload it all here: http://www.mediafire.com/folder/04wpfamyd7mvh/errorncode

Comment: It seems you are setting the jCas's text twice, could that be?

Comment: You mean where is it ? If the Annotator alone, I can call it and run from another test file. It only get problem when I add to the pipeline, behind the POSTagger, '    aggregate.add(FeatureExtractionAnnotator.createDescriptor());
'